# Swapping with for loop in Python don't work well

Tags: python, for-loop, swap

I have a list with unknown length and values. I want to swap only when I see 'G' after 'B' one time for each round.
for example:
I have a list `["B", "G", "G", "B", "G"]`
I waited `["G", "B", "G", "G", "B"]`
But the result is => `['G', 'G', 'B', 'G', 'B']`
This is a problem on Codeforces site: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/266/B
*If there is something that is not clear, please give me some advice to promote my skills.*

I tried:

```
item1, item2 = item2, item1
```

It swapped first 3 strings from the last example not what I want 'only two strings' `['G', 'G', 'B'...]` but I waited `['G', 'B', 'G'...]`
Could you understand?
**This is my code:**

```
# If you find 'G' after 'B' swap them and go through the loop without accessing the last items. 
queue_time = list(map(int, input().split()))
queue = queue_time[0]
time = queue_time[-1]
persons = ["B", "G", "G"]

while time > 0:
  for i in range(len(persons)-1):
    if persons[i] == "B" and persons[i + 1] == "G":
      persons[i], persons[i +1] = persons[i +1], persons[i]
    if persons[i + 1]:
      continue
  time -= 1
print(persons)
```

Comment: "How can I swap only 2 items and go to another 2 items without swapping the items I've already swapped."  How is your code supposed to tell what you have "already swapped"?

Comment: You could advance your for loop by two positions on each iteration, instead of one.

Comment: I want to swap only if there is "G" after "B" only those and move to the next two without including any items I have swapped. Do you understand me?

Answer (score 1):

You could remember in a variable whether you swapped the previous pair and check that among your checks. Or you could loop with `while i < n - 1:` (instead of the `for` loop) and increase `i` by 1 or 2 as needed. But it's much simpler to keep the input a string instead of a list, and to use its `replace` method.

```
n, t = map(int, input().split())
S = input()
for _ in range(t):
    S = S.replace('BG', 'GB')
print(S)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to mark swapped elements once you've swapped them, so as not to process them again. You don't need a separate sequence for that, since you can just step forward by an extra step after you swap:

```
ppl = list('BGGBG')
just_swapped = False
for i in range(len(ppl) - 1):
    if just_swapped:
        just_swapped = False
        continue
    if ppl[i : i + 2] == ['B', 'G']:
        ppl[i : i+2] = ppl[i+1 : i-1 if i else None : -1]
        just_swapped = True
```

If you had a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, you could remove `just_swapped` and simply increment the index one extra time.

In either case, the result is

```
>>> ppl
['G', 'B', 'G', 'G', 'B']
```

Comment: Can You explain (None : -1) in more details? And if possible, give me links for articles

Comment: @Hamza. It's basic python indexing notation. The index is `(i+1) : (i-1 if i else None) : (-1)` (parentheses added for charity). It means go from `i+1` (inclusive) to `i-1` (exclusive), in steps of `-1`. I.e., `i+1, i`. The ternary operator in the middle is necessary because when `i == 0`, `i-1` is a negative number, which indexes into the end of the array. So in that case we want the slice `1::-1` instead of `1:-1:-1`. The empty slice argument is equivalent to `None`. You can look at `slice` objects for more info.

Comment: Also, don't forget to upvote and select an answer when you get a chance.